# How to generate a random number on image-click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to generate random number on click on image. This is the code. I don't know what I am missing.

```js
$(".crystal-image1").on("click", function() {
  var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9) + 1;
  $(this).val()
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="crystal-image1" src="http://www.lightworkersworld.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/Crystal-Quartz.jpg" alt="crystal">
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access an element by its id you should be doing `$("#crystal-image1").on("click", function() {` instead  `$(".crystal-image1").on("click", function() {`. That is the trouble. In JS,`#` is to access by id and `.` is to access by class name

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it look like this?

```
$("#crystal-image1").on("click", function() {
  var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9) + 1;
  console.log(random);
});
```

btw why are you using $(this).val()? Normally this method is to pick up a value from an input ?

And as sureshprasanna70 states '.' is for class accessor and # is for id!